# Use of AsNoTracking in ASP.Net Core docs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to understand the use of AsNoTracking when editing an entity in the following code from ASP.Net Core docs, found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authorization/secure-data/samples/final2/Pages/Contacts/Edit.cshtml.cs):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    // Fetch Contact from DB to get OwnerID.
    var contact = await Context
        .Contact.AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ContactId == id);

    if (contact == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var isAuthorized = await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
                                             User, contact,
                                             ContactOperations.Update);
    if (!isAuthorized.Succeeded)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult();
    }

    Contact.OwnerID = contact.OwnerID;

    Context.Attach(Contact).State = EntityState.Modified;

    …

    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

The summary for AsNoTracking states:

> Disabling change tracking is useful for read-only scenarios because it
>   avoids the overhead of setting up change tracking for each entity
>   instance. You should not disable change tracking if you want to
>   manipulate entity instances and persist those changes to the database
>   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges.

Clearly this isn't a read-only scenario and the only reason this method is running is to attempt to update the entity in the database.

Is there an explanation for why this code seems to be going against the advice given in the AsNoTracking summary?

Comment: No good reason for this, as the code ends up *re*attaching the same entity. Lots of bad possibilitie: lack of knowledge, cargo cult programming, copy/paste programming. Attempt to cover up bad performance by using "performance" hacks.

Comment: I would hope there is a good reason as these are the official Microsoft docs and I would look to them to provide best practices.

Comment: that's a link to a Github sample, not the ASP.NET docs. That said, you'l find several examples in the docs are too clever - they try to show multiple things at the same time and end up *obscuring* whatever they wanted to show

Comment: It's from the code used in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I think I understand the "cleverness" here - the contact is loaded without tracking to reduce overhead if `Update` isn't authorized. If it is, the object is reattached and an attempt to `Approve` is made. Depending on that status, its final status is updated and finally saved. Micro-optimization and lack of proper commenting make all this a rather confusing example

Comment: if you check the tutorial itself, `EditModel` uses AsNoTracking but `DetailModel` doesn't, even though the flow is the same. The only difference is that `EditModel.PostAsync` calls `AuthorizeAsync` twice.

Comment: I think @PanagiotisKanavos is correct. It's a micro-optimization for the case where no update actually needs to be made. However, as sample code, it's pretty bad to do it this way because it's not clear why they did it, and therefore, prone to confusing people or just plain causing issues from copy-paste errors and such. FWIW, this isn't even the optimal way, as it would be better if they first attached the entity, and *then* changed the properties. That way, EF could do partial updates.

Comment: For what it's worth, I created an issue for this, which has now been closed. https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/9842#event-2011502096. Seems they opted to remove `AsNoTracking` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `AsNoTracking()` is used when fetching the `Contact` instance is also the reason why the contact gets reattached back to the `context` with it's `State` set to `EntityState.Modified` - as `contact` is not tracked by the `context`, you need to explicitly let the `context` know that this entity has been modified.

If `AsNoTracking()` was not used, that wouldn't be needed.

[NoTracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#5-notracking-queries) (MS Docs)

Generally, you benefit from `AsNoTracking()` in read-only scenarios (the R part of [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete))

As for the potential intent of the use of `AsNoTracking()` in the snippet, @Panagiotis Kanavos's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636686/use-of-asnotracking-in-asp-net-core-docs/53637035#comment94133683_53636686) is IMHO spot on:

> "I think I understand the "cleverness" here - the contact is loaded without tracking to reduce overhead if Update isn't authorized. If it is, the object is reattached and an attempt to Approve is made. Depending on that status, its final status is updated and finally saved."

Comment: The OP is asking why `AsNoTracking()` was used in the first place

Comment: And frankly, I don't see a good reason to use `AsNoTracking`, especially not in a tutorial

Comment: Ah yes, you are right - i've also just read your comment about the "cleverness" of the snippet - quite a convoluted example indeed.